# Which RSS tags can contain HTML?

Tags: html, xml, encoding, rss, escaping

TLDR: Which RSS tags are rendered as HTML, instead of being treated just as text? `<description>` is one of them.

---

I'm generating RSS feed from users input. I keep their original texts in the DB and escape on output when rendering HTML, so that it's not treated as HTML markup, but just as text.

I want to apply the same strategy to RSS feeds. I always escape for XML, but I'm not sure which RSS tags require HTML escaping.

`<description>` requires HTML escaping for sure, as I don't want the users input to be treated as HTML and RSS clients do HTML–parse descriptions.

For example, a user enters `<b>test</b>`, so I escape it for HTML (`&lt;b&gt;test&lt/b&gt;`) and finally for XML so that it's outputted like `<description>&amp;lt;b&amp;gt;test&amp;lt/b&amp;gt;</description>`.

---

Which tags require HTML–escaping besides `description`?

I assume it's up to the RSS client to decide, but what's the common practice? What is that most clients do?

Comment: I never could get my head around RSS and tend to use Atom where I need to provide a feed. It was designed after RSS had been around for a while and had the opportunity to learn from RSS's mistakes.

Comment: @Quentin Yeah, I'm probably gonna create Atom feeds as well, but for now I'm dealing with RSS ;-)

Comment: Are you tried html in CDATA. http://www.rssboard.org/rss-encoding-examples

Comment: @SuatAtan CDATA is another strategy for XML–encoding. This is what I'm always doing anyway. What I want to know is, when should I encode for HTML context?